# Disabling eventListener after a certain number of clicks

Tags: javascript, event-listener

How can I disable an event listener after a certain number of clicks are received?

I think the below code is wrong as I am calling for event Listener to be disabled from within the event listener.

```js
let cells = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');

let temp = 0;
function clicker (x) {
  temp += 1;
  console.log('clicked',x.target.classList[1],temp);
  x.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  if (temp === 3) {
    cells.forEach(c => c.removeEventListener('click', (el) => clicker(el)));
  }
  return;
}

cells.forEach(c => c.addEventListener('click', (el) => clicker(el)));
```

```css
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,90px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 90px);
  row-gap: 5px;
  column-gap: 5px;
}

.cell {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class = "cell fir"></div>
  <div class = "cell sec"></div>
  <div class = "cell thi"></div>
  <div class = "cell fou"></div>
  <div class = "cell fif"></div>
  <div class = "cell six"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function passed to `removeEventListener` has to be the same as the one passed to `addEventListener`. Since you're using an anonymous function in each place, they won't be the same functions.

Just use the name of the function rather than an anonymous function that calls it.

```js
let cells = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');

let temp = 0;
function clicker (x) {
  temp += 1;
  console.log('clicked', temp);
  if (temp === 3) {
    cells.forEach(c => c.removeEventListener('click', clicker));
  }
  return;
}

cells.forEach(c => c.addEventListener('click', clicker));
```

```css
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,90px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 90px);
  row-gap: 5px;
  column-gap: 5px;
}

.cell {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class = "cell fir"></div>
  <div class = "cell sec"></div>
  <div class = "cell thi"></div>
  <div class = "cell fou"></div>
  <div class = "cell fif"></div>
  <div class = "cell six"></div>
</div>
```